2021: a year in moderation

As we say goodbye to the old year and welcome the new one, we have a tradition of sharing moderation stats for the preceding calendar year.
As most of you here are aware, sites on the Stack Exchange network are moderated somewhat differently to other sites on the web:

We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
-- A Theory of Moderation

That doesn't eliminate the need for having moderators altogether, but it does mean that the bulk of moderation work is carried out by regular folks. Every bit of time and effort y'all contribute to the site gives you access to more privileges you can use to help in this effort, all of which produce a cumulative effect that makes a big difference.
So as we say goodbye to 2021, let us look back at what we accomplished as a community... by looking at some exciting stats. Below is a breakdown of moderation actions performed on Chinese Language over the past 12 months:




Action
Moderators
Community¹




Users suspended²
0
10


Users destroyed³
1
0


Users deleted
1
0


Tasks reviewed⁴: Suggested Edit queue
37
166


Tasks reviewed⁴: Reopen Vote queue
0
5


Tasks reviewed⁴: Low Quality Posts queue
4
257


Tasks reviewed⁴: Late Answer queue
8
134


Tasks reviewed⁴: First questions queue
3
69


Tasks reviewed⁴: First Post queue
69
381


Tasks reviewed⁴: First answers queue
2
115


Tasks reviewed⁴: Close Votes queue
3
207


Questions unprotected
0
8


Questions reopened
6
0


Questions protected
2
13


Questions migrated
1
0


Questions flagged⁵
0
53


Questions closed
100
7


Question flags handled⁵
31
22


Posts undeleted
7
16


Posts locked
0
4


Posts deleted⁶
170
197


Posts bumped
0
173


Comments undeleted
14
0


Comments flagged
0
71


Comments deleted⁷
161
290


Comment flags handled
44
28


Answers flagged
0
329


Answer flags handled
305
24


All comments on a post moved to chat
5
0



Footnotes
¹ "Community" here refers both to the membership of Chinese Language without diamonds next to their names, and to the automated systems otherwise known as user #-1.
² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.
³ A "destroyed" user is deleted along with all that they had posted: questions, answers, comments. Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.
⁴ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.
⁵ Includes close flags (but not close or reopen votes).
⁶ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.
⁷ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).
Further reading:

Wanna see how these numbers have changed over time? We posted a similar report here last year: 2020: a year in moderation

You can also check out this report on other sites

Or peruse detailed information on the number of questions closed and reopened across all sites


Wishing everyone a happy 2022! ^_^
